# R: the usage of general parameter formula for classifiers

Tags: r, scikit-learn, formula

In R, `formula` is a common parameter of classifier such as `glm`, `tree` and `svm`. However, as a user of Sklearn, I can't find parameter like `formula` when feeding SVM with data in Sklearn.

For example, the chunk code in [document of SVM in Scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html)

```
>>> from sklearn import svm
>>> X = [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
>>> y = [0, 1]
>>> clf = svm.SVC()
>>> clf.fit(X, y)  
#SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3,
#gamma=0.0, kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
#shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

On the other hand, in package [`e1071`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/e1071.pdf) in R

```
data(cats, package = "MASS")
m <- svm(Sex~., data = cats)
```

There is parameter `Sex~.` as formula specified to train the SVM, which is not the case when using Scikit-learn.

I am then curious about the particular reason behind specifying `formula` when training SVM in R. Since we don't have to do so in Sklearn.

Comment: Do you mind to share some code? As it, your question is quite unclear.

Comment: Don't you have to specify `x` and `y` in `scikit-learn` ? Formula is the same, in addition to plain `x` and `y` in formula you can specify transformations to `x` or `y`. Like instead of `y ~ x` you can specify `y ~ x + x^2`, which will fit both linear and quadratic terms to `y`.